# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{3^n}\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}+b^{\frac{1}{n}}+c^{\frac{1}{n}} \right)^n$ where $a,b,c>0$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}}{3} \bigg)^n, \quad \textrm{$a>0$, $b>0$ and $c>0$.}$$

I had an idea to present the terms and decompose them as $1+(a-1), 1+(b-1)$ and $1+(c-1)$, but in this way I got to the answer $\exp(\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c-1))$ while the correct answer is $(abc)^{1/3}$.

Comment: Use $$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^x.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the limit $L$. Then $$ \log L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n} + c^{1/n}}{3}\right) }{\frac 1n}$$

This is a $\frac 00$ situation. Apply L’Hôpital’s:

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ \frac{3}{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}}\cdot \frac 13\cdot \left( a^{1/n}\log a \cdot \frac{-1}{n^2} + b^{1/n} \log b\cdot \frac{-1}{n^2} + c^{1/n}\log c\cdot \frac{-1}{n^2} \right) }{\frac{-1}{n^2}} \\ = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ a^{1/n}\log a+ b^{1/n} \log b + c^{1/n} \log c}{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}} \\ = \frac{\log a+\log b+ \log c}{3} \\ = \log(abc)^{\frac 13} $$

and so $$L= (abc)^{\frac 13} $$